# Is there a sign for "x's negation equals y"?

Tags: inequality, notation

For example, let M and N be two real numbers. M is smaller than N. Now I negate the inequality, such that now M is greater or equal to N.

$M < N ≟ M \geq N$

Is there a sign to replace '≟' in the expression above?

Comment: $\neg$ ${}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're talking about *equivalence* of a proposition to the *negation* of another. In which case, the "exclusive or" should do:

$$ (M < N) \;\veebar\; (M \geqslant N) $$

asserts that exactly one of the two propositions $M < N$ and $M \geqslant N$ is true. As suggested in the comments (and in Ilya's answer), though, explicitly writing one of

$$\begin{gather*}
(M < N) \;\equiv\; \neg (M \geqslant N) \\
(M < N) \;\iff\; \neg (M \geqslant N)
\end{gather*}$$

would probably be clearer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I also liked to see the '≡' in usage. I never used it but I have been curious about it.

Comment: @GuiRitter: It is essentially standard notation for logical equivalence ($A \equiv \neg \neg A$) and congruence in modular arithmetic ($5 \equiv 12 \bmod{7}$); it is nonstandard but common for identities, ie. an implicit universal quantifier ($\cos^2(x) +\sin^2(x) \equiv 1$ or $f \equiv 0$ to describe a function which is zero everywhere), definitions of variables (in place eg. of $:=$), and perhaps similar emphatic notions of equality or similarity.

Answer (score 3):

$\quad\quad\Leftrightarrow \neg$